# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' resizing image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to resize a .tif image in python.
But when im trying to run the code I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
# Open de beeldfile

image = cv2.imread(fullinname)

# Bepaal afmetingen en aantal kleurkanalen

width = image.shape[1]

height = image.shape[0]

colors = image.shape[2]

print ("{} pixels breed".format(width))
print ("{} pixels hoog".format(height))
print ("{} kleur kanalen".format(colors))

img = cv2.resize(image, (512, 512))
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Nope, only got 1 cv2.imread in my file

Comment: If none of the 5 answers posted there don't solve your issue then maybe [any of these](https://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=python+cv2.imread+returns+none&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=NF7pWLCjNMuC8Qe4hqPACw) can help? This is a fairly common issue, I'm sure some research would yield a solution. (see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users))

Comment: Can you debug the `fullinname` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here the code I was running on my box:

```
import cv2
# Open de beeldfile
image = cv2.imread("/fullPathImageName.jpg")
# Bepaal afmetingen en aantal kleurkanalen

width = image.shape[1]
height = image.shape[0]
colors = image.shape[2]
print ("{} pixels breed".format(width))
print ("{} pixels hoog".format(height))
print ("{} kleur kanalen".format(colors))

img = cv2.resize(image, (512, 512)) 

width = img.shape[1]
height = img.shape[0]
colors = img.shape[2]
print ("{} pixels breed".format(width))
print ("{} pixels hoog".format(height))
print ("{} kleur kanalen".format(colors))
```

Here what it prints:

```
python -u "cv2questionImageResize_Cg.py"
816 pixels breed
612 pixels hoog
3 kleur kanalen
512 pixels breed
512 pixels hoog
3 kleur kanalen
```

So from my point of view there is nothing to solve here ...
EXCEPT ...

> put "fullinname" in quotation marks

and check if the file exists and is ok.